# AWK - Adding new line based on text in previous line?

Tags: awk

So I have some database table info in a file that looks like this:

```
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-19_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.8 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
18.9 G    56.8 G    def-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-27_random_letters_random_numbers
110.4 M   331.2 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-28_random_letters_random_numbers
55.1 K    165.3 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
50.7 K    152.1 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-24_random_letters_random_numbers
49.6 K    148.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-25_random_letters_random_numbers
48.6 K    138.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-26_random_letters_random_numbers
```

Basically, I need it to look like this:

```
2.6 G     7.7 G     qabc-def-ghi_2021-09-19_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.7 G     qabc-def-ghi_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.8 G     qabc-def-ghi_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers

18.9 G    56.8 G    def-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers

110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-wwwdef_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-wwwdef_2021-09-27_random_letters_random_numbers
110.4 M   331.2 M   ghi-abc-wwwdef_2021-09-28_random_letters_random_numbers

55.1 K    165.3 K   jkl-deghi-def_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
50.7 K    152.1 K   jkl-deghi-def_2021-09-24_random_letters_random_numbers
49.6 K    148.8 K   jkl-deghi-def_2021-09-25_random_letters_random_numbers
48.6 K    138.8 K   jkl-deghi-def_2021-09-26_random_letters_random_numbers
```

Where there is a new line after the start of each unique table-name prefix. Right now I'm having to do all of this manually for hundreds of table names. Also, if there is a way to count how many times each table name occurs, that would be great too.

Here is the code I got so far @Cyrus:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ _]+"} NR==1{last=$(NF-1)} NR>1 && last!=$(NF-1){printf RS} {last=$(NF-1); print}' test2.txt
```

Here is the output

```
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-19_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.8 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
18.9 G    56.8 G    def-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-27_random_letters_random_numbers
110.4 M   331.2 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-28_random_letters_random_numbers
55.1 K    165.3 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
50.7 K    152.1 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-24_random_letters_random_numbers
49.6 K    148.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-25_random_letters_random_numbers
48.6 K    138.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-26_random_letters_random_numbers
```

This command works for table names like these:

```
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-19
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-20
2.6 G     7.8 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-21
18.9 G    56.8 G    def-abc-def_2021-09-21
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-21
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-27
110.4 M   331.2 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-28
55.1 K    165.3 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-20
50.7 K    152.1 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-24
49.6 K    148.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-25
48.6 K    138.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- all input lines have a total of 5 space-delimited fields that look like: `#.# {G,K,M} #.# {G,K,M} <table-name-prefix>_YYYY-MM-DD_random_letters_random_numbers`
- input file has already been sorted by `<table-name-prefix>`
- objective is to add a blank line to the output before we process a line with a new/different `<table-name-prefix>`
- OP mentions keeping track of how many times each unique `<table-name-prefix>` is seen, but since there's no mention of what to do with said number I'll just print it on the new 'blank' line (for now)
- expected output is to look like the 2nd block of data provided in the question (with proviso that `<table-name-prefix>` counts are placed in the 'blank' lines)

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '{ split($5,arr,"_")                              # split field #5 on "_" delimiter
       tabname=arr[1]                                 # grab table name
       if (tabname != prevname && prevname != "" ) {  # if this is a new table name then ...
          printf "%s\n", count                        # print a new line with a count of the last table name and then ... 
          count=0
       }
       print                                          # print current line
       count++                                        # increment count for table name
       prevname = tabname                             # keep track of previous table name
     }
END  { printf "%s\n", count }                         # flush last table name count to stdout
' test2.txt
```

This generates:

```
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-19_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.8 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
3
18.9 G    56.8 G    def-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
1
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-27_random_letters_random_numbers
110.4 M   331.2 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-28_random_letters_random_numbers
3
55.1 K    165.3 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
50.7 K    152.1 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-24_random_letters_random_numbers
49.6 K    148.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-25_random_letters_random_numbers
48.6 K    138.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-26_random_letters_random_numbers
4
```

Comment: If you use `printf "%d\n", count` or `print count+0` instead of `printf "%s\n", count` then you would still get numeric output even if the input was empty.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer! What you did with the counts was just fine, but ill play around with them to see if I can get them to all print at the end(maybe in an array or something)

Comment: at the bottom of the answer, and before the comments, you'll see a link `edited ...`; click on that link to see an earlier version of my code where I was storing counts in an array; if you're using `GNU awk` you can use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` to help with sorting an array before printing it - see [custom array traversal](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) for details

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can just do:

```
awk 'last && $5 != last { print count; count=0 } {last = $5; count++ } 1' FS='[ _]*'
```

eg:

```
$ cat input
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-19_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.8 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
18.9 G    56.8 G    def-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-27_random_letters_random_numbers
110.4 M   331.2 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-28_random_letters_random_numbers
55.1 K    165.3 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
50.7 K    152.1 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-24_random_letters_random_numbers
49.6 K    148.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-25_random_letters_random_numbers
48.6 K    138.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-26_random_letters_random_numbers
$ awk 'last && $5 != last { print count; count=0 } {last = $5; count++ } 1' FS='[ _]*' input
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-19_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.8 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
3
18.9 G    56.8 G    def-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
1
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-27_random_letters_random_numbers
110.4 M   331.2 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-28_random_letters_random_numbers
3
55.1 K    165.3 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
50.7 K    152.1 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-24_random_letters_random_numbers
49.6 K    148.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-25_random_letters_random_numbers
48.6 K    138.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-26_random_letters_random_numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]_]+' '(NR>1) && ($5 != prev){print ""} {print; prev=$5}' file
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-19_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.8 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers

18.9 G    56.8 G    def-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers

110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-27_random_letters_random_numbers
110.4 M   331.2 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-28_random_letters_random_numbers

55.1 K    165.3 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
50.7 K    152.1 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-24_random_letters_random_numbers
49.6 K    148.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-25_random_letters_random_numbers
48.6 K    138.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-26_random_letters_random_numbers
```

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]_]+' '(NR>1) && ($5 != prev){print cnt; cnt=0} {print; prev=$5; cnt++} END{if (cnt) print cnt}' file
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-19_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.7 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
2.6 G     7.8 G     abc-def-ghi_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
3
18.9 G    56.8 G    def-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
1
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-21_random_letters_random_numbers
110.3 M   331.0 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-27_random_letters_random_numbers
110.4 M   331.2 M   ghi-abc-def_2021-09-28_random_letters_random_numbers
3
55.1 K    165.3 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-20_random_letters_random_numbers
50.7 K    152.1 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-24_random_letters_random_numbers
49.6 K    148.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-25_random_letters_random_numbers
48.6 K    138.8 K   jkl-ghi-def_2021-09-26_random_letters_random_numbers
4
```

The `if (cnt)` in  the END sections is just so you don't print a null string or zero if the input file is empty.